# How do I make a module in PLT Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, racket

I tried doing this:

```
#lang scheme
(module duck scheme/base
      (provide num-eggs quack)
      (define num-eggs 2)
      (define (quack n)
        (unless (zero? n)
          (printf "quack\n")
          (quack (sub1 n)))))
```

But I get this error:

```
module: illegal use (not at top-level) in: 
(module duck scheme/base (provide num-eggs quack) (define num-eggs 2) (define (quack n) (unless (zero? n) (printf "quack\n") (quack (sub1 n)))))
```

what is the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `(module duck scheme/base` line (and the closing paren).

When you start your code with `#lang scheme`, it's effectively putting your code in a module that uses the `scheme` language.  You can also use `#lang scheme/base` if you want the smaller language instead.

(To really get convinced, do this:

```
(parameterize ([read-accept-reader #t])
  (call-with-input-file "some file" read))
```

over some source file that uses `#lang` and see what you get.)

(And BTW, the title of your question is bad -- it should be "PLT Scheme", since this is not relevant to other implementations.)